# ERROR "Requested JSON parse failed" al intentar obtener informacion de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mvc

Estoy intentando obtener información de mysql usando `ajax`, estoy usando `php` con patron `mvc`, se supone que el `ajax` debe acceder al método del controlador, el método obtiene información del modelo y guarda la información en una variable.

Luego esa variable la codifico en un `Json` para el `ajax`, pero la respuesta me aparece con un "null" al final del `json` y creo que por eso me aparece el error "Requested JSON parse failed" pero no sé como solucionarlo.

el problema es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código del `ajax` es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById("categoria").value;
    var parametros = {
        "buscar":"1",
        "id":select
    };
    $(document).on('change','#categoria',function(){
        console.log("id a enviar = "+select);
           $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            dataType: "text", //cambiar a JSON
            url: "obtenerCategoria",
            method: "post",
            beforeSend: function()
            {console.log("enviando");},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {alert("Error");
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    console.log('Requested page not found [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
                    console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.'); //ESTE ERROR MUESTRA
                } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                    console.log('Time out error.');
                } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                    console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            },
            complete: function()
            {console.log("Listo!!");},
            success: function(valores) {
                console.log(valores);
                console.log(valores.nombre); //esto no funciona aparece "undefined"
            }
});
    });
</script>
```

el código del controlador:

```
function obtenerCategoria()
   {
    if(isset($_POST["buscar"]))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $resultadoBusqueda = $this->model->obtenerCategoria($id);
        
        $valores = json_encode($resultadoBusqueda,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $valores;
    }
   
}
```

El código del modelo:

```
public function obtenerCategoria($idCat)
      {
        try{
            $query = $this->db->connect()->query("SELECT nombre,informacion FROM categoria WHERE idCat=$idCat");
            $row = $query->fetchAll();
            return $row;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Si tan solo hubieses puesto código en vez de imagenes.

Comment: Ese `NULL` al final del JSON está haciendo que el cliente reciba un JSON inválido. ¿De dónde sale ese `NULL`? Dado que sólo muestras algunas funciones del código PHP, no el contexto completo, no podemos verificarlo nosotros, verifica tú.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre como resolver mi problema.
para resolver lo del null solo tuve que agregar `exit();` al final del if y eso era suficiente para quitar el null pero igual daba el error "Requested JSON parse failed"

```
function obtenerCategoria(){
     if(isset($_POST["buscar"]))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $resultadoBusqueda = $this->model->obtenerCategoria($id);
        $valores = json_encode($resultadoBusqueda,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $valores;

    }else echo json_encode([]);  //devolver un  Json vacío

    exit();   
  }
```

para resolver el error "Requested JSON parse failed" tuve que escribir toda la url del sitio, es decir, `http://localhost:8081/Prueba5/mvc/NombreControlador/NombreMetodo`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById("categoria");
    $(document).on('change','#categoria',function(){ //al pulsar una de las opciones del select
        var parametros = {
        "buscar":"1",
        "id":select.value
        };
           $.ajax({
    /*Tengo un archivo llamado config.php dentro tengo una constante con la url del sito
        a la que puedo acceder en cualquier pagina php con solo llamarla, es la siguiente:

define("URL", "localhost:8081/Prueba5/mvc/"); //es para definir una url absoluta, 
para en caso de cambiarlo a otro servidor solo se debe cambiar esta parte y no en todas 
las paginas uno por uno
            */
                                //URL del sitio/controlador/metodo
            url: "<?php echo constant("URL"); ?>Categoria/obtenerCategoria",
            data: parametros,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            ContentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function()
            {alert("enviando");},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {alert("Error");
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested page not found [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.'); //ESTE ERROR MUESTRA
                } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                    alert('Time out error.');
                } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            },
            complete: function()
            {alert("Listo!!");},
            success: function(valores) {
                console.log(valores);
                console.log(valores[0].nombre); //esto ahora sí funciona
            }
        });
    });
```

Y ahora sí me da resultado que quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tienes un error de concepto

Si hace  una solicitud `AJAX` al controlador  el cual contiene una `función` definida pero no `invocada`  es normal que aparezca la respuesta en `null`

Dicho esto :

El código del controlador debería ser algo así  :

```php
   function obtenerCategoria($_POST){
      $id = $_POST["id"];
      $resultadoBusqueda = $this->model->obtenerCategoria($id);
      return json_encode($resultadoBusqueda,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);   
    }

//llamar a la funcion si hay post
if(isset($_POST["buscar"])) obtenerCategoria($_POST);
else echo json_encode([]);  //devolver un  Json vacío
```